# Referencing cell in csv file using vba

Tags: excel, vba

How do you open a csv file in VBA and reference a cell in the csv file.
This seems like it should be very simple but I have been troubleshooting this for over an hour now and haven't found a solution.

Below is the code I am trying to run

```
Dim ReportBook As Workbook

Set ReportBook = Workbooks.Open("N:\ECM\APSActuarial\ECM\user_folders\name\IMD&CALM\CALM_MACRO\ML_TCM-Spread_TLIC_Q_14_0Empty.csv")

'Print HLV
ReportBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cell(10, 4) = HLVBase
```

I keep getting the following error
"subscript out of range"

Does anybody know what's going on here?

EDIT:
I solved this.
I feel really stupid. It's "cells" not "cell"

Comment: best to delete this question altogether

Comment: well may be someone else will have the same issue